# MySQL IN Clause in SQL query with User Defined Function

Tags: mysql, database

I am using following query to update all the children of particular topic.

```
UPDATE topics SET reuse = 0 WHERE topic_id IN (SELECT GetChildTopics(187));
```

Where

```
SELECT GetChildTopics(187);
```

returns "188,190,189" but my update query is updating only first row with topic_id = 188, instead of updating first topic only, it should update all 3 topics.

When I put the values manually it works fine.

```
UPDATE topics SET reuse = 0 WHERE topic_id IN (188,190,189);
```

Can anyone suggest what's wrong I am doing here?

Here is the code for GetChildTopics MySQL Function

```
    CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` FUNCTION `GetAncestry`(GivenID INT) RETURNS varchar(1024) CHARSET latin1
    DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
    DECLARE rv VARCHAR(1024);
    DECLARE cm CHAR(1);
    DECLARE ch INT;

    SET rv = '';
    SET cm = '';
    SET ch = GivenID;
    WHILE ch > 0 DO
        SELECT IFNULL(parent_topic_id,-1) INTO ch FROM
        (SELECT parent_topic_id FROM topic_list WHERE id = ch) A;
        IF ch > 0 THEN
            SET rv = CONCAT(rv,cm,ch);
            SET cm = ',';
        END IF;
    END WHILE;
    RETURN rv;
END
```

Comment: Returns the function the string '188,190,189' or a resultset with 3 records?

Comment: Better share your `GetChildTopics` function

Comment: @Frank function returns a string with comma separated values

Comment: Thats the problem. It must return a result set in this context

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this;)

```
UPDATE topics SET reuse = 0 WHERE FIND_IN_SET(topic_id, GetChildTopics(187));
```